# Maven ArcheType Filter On Yaml File

Tags: java, maven, yaml, velocity, maven-archetype

When building my Archetype I received an error on parsing of a yaml file

I have set fileSet on ***archetype-metadata.xml***  for yaml in this way

```
<fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.yml</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
```

this is my ***yaml*** file

```
spring:
 application:
  name: ${applicationName}-service
logging:
 pattern:
  console: ""
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
server:  
  port: ${PORT:4001}
```

This is error on ***clean and install*** of my ArcheType

```
 org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered ":4001}" at archetype-resources/src/main/resources/bootstrap.yml[line 11, column 15]
Was expecting one of:
    "[" ...
    "}" ...

at org.apache.velocity.Template.process(Template.java:151)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.loadResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:437)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:352)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1533)
at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:343)
at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.processTemplate(DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.java:770)
at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.processFileSet(DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.java:571)
at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.processTemplates(DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.java:820)
at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.processArchetypeTemplates(DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.java:545)
at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.processFilesetProject(DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.java:663)
at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.processFilesetModule(DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.java:596)
at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.generateArchetype(DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.java:207)
at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultArchetypeGenerator.processFileSetArchetype(DefaultArchetypeGenerator.java:135)
at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultArchetypeGenerator.generateArchetype(DefaultArchetypeGenerator.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultArchetypeGenerator.generateArchetype(DefaultArchetypeGenerator.java:149)
at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.IntegrationTestMojo.generate(IntegrationTestMojo.java:535)
at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.IntegrationTestMojo.processIntegrationTest(IntegrationTestMojo.java:494)
at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.IntegrationTestMojo.execute(IntegrationTestMojo.java:313)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

I'm using

- Eclipse Oxigen
- jdk 1.8
- Maven 3.3.1

Comment: {$PORT:4001} is a placeholder Spring with default value.

Answer (score 3):

Velocity will try to get variable after `$` (Dollar Sign), so I suggest you trick velocity to ignore it and then your Spring will get the required output `${PORT:4001}` after velocity finish transform the template.

```
#set ( $dollarSign = "$")
port: $dollarSign{PORT:4001}
```

it should be ${dollarSign}{PORT:4001}

Answer (score 0):

Alas, the `${PORT:4001}` syntax is not (yet?) supported by Velocity.

So you have to use `#if($PORT)$PORT#{else}4001#end`